# How far off-plane of a 4th-corner probe should be cause for concern during bed leveling?

Tags: marlin, calibration, lulzbot

On my TAZ Pro, after modifying and reinstalling my build surface, I have the following verbose output from running self-calibration:

```
> [21:30:51] G29 V4
< [21:30:53] G29 Auto Bed Leveling
< [21:31:01] Bed X: -10.000 Y: -9.000 Z: -0.010
< [21:31:11] Bed X: 288.000 Y: -9.000 Z: -1.347
< [21:31:21] Bed X: 288.000 Y: 291.000 Z: -0.937
< [21:31:31] Bed X: -10.000 Y: 291.000 Z: -0.061
< [21:31:31] 4th probe point, distance from plane: 0.46
< [21:31:31] Eqn coefficients: a: -0.00371342 b: 0.00059800 d: -0.15685220
< [21:31:31] Mean of sampled points: -0.58869988
< [21:31:31] 
< [21:31:31] Bed Height Topography:
< [21:31:31]   +--- BACK --+
< [21:31:31]   |           |
< [21:31:31] L |    (+)    | R
< [21:31:31] E |           | I
< [21:31:31] F | (-) N (+) | G
< [21:31:31] T |           | H
< [21:31:31]   |    (-)    | T
< [21:31:31]   |           |
< [21:31:31]   O-- FRONT --+
< [21:31:31] (0,0)
< [21:31:31] +0.52750 -0.34810
< [21:31:31] +0.57910 -0.75850
< [21:31:31] 
< [21:31:31] 
< [21:31:31] Corrected Bed Height vs. Bed Topology:
< [21:31:31] +0.00001 +0.23100
< [21:31:31] +0.23101 +0.00000
< [21:31:31] 
< [21:31:31] 
< [21:31:31] 
< [21:31:31] Bed Level Correction Matrix:
< [21:31:31] +0.999993 +0.000000 -0.003713 
< [21:31:31] +0.000002 +1.000000 +0.000598 
< [21:31:31] +0.003713 -0.000598 +0.999993
```

How can I evaluate whether this is a reasonable result, or if it means something is broken and needs to be fixed?

(I'm definitely seeing very significant variances in actual distance between the head and the build surface with the same "Z height" according to the LCD controller; I'm trying to determine whether this could be a bed-leveling issue).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what I'm seeing, but it looks to me as though your bed is now warped. In the correction matrix, if you look at the three corrections from the upper left to the lower right,  you'll see it is ~+1 for all three, while the other six points are at or near zero (one is even below zero). This would put a crown in the bed from upper left to lower right corners. I would bet if you put a straight edge on your bed in the upper right to lower left directions, you'd see this. I'm not sure how it would affect your prints, but I bet it will deform them.